# How to list all Presto workers?

Tags: presto

I want to get a list of all connected workers so that I can detect which worker is not working.

I tried `select * from sys.node;` but it doesn't work.

I'm using Presto 0.128.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For 0.128 version, the sql should be this:

```
select * from system.runtime.nodes
```